# R Markdown: output with weird characters

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio

I am seeking your help as I encountered a curious R markdown issue when using scripts sourced from external. My rmd. file contains several code chunks that generate tables. For some of the chunks, they work very well with scripts sourced from external, for example:

```
source(
  here::here("file_name_1",
             "file_name_2",
             "file_name_3",
             "file_name_4",
             "*********.R"),
  echo       = FALSE,
  print.eval = TRUE
)
```

However, some chunks with external script sourced using exactly the same code template as above do not give me the output (which is a table).

I ended up re-editing the source script and rmd file. First, in the script, I assigned the table with a name, e.g., `Table_1 <- [codes that generate the table]` . Second, in the rmd file, I added `Table_1` below the code chunk to call the table generation function. For example:

```
source(
  here::here("file_name_1",
             "file_name_2",
             "file_name_3",
             "file_name_4",
             "*********.R"),
  echo       = FALSE,
  print.eval = TRUE
)

Table_1
```

Then I re-run the rmd, it seemed like starting to work and did give me a table that I want, but there were minor issues: some characters / signs in the table were weird. For example, **1-18** became **1â€“18**.

Any ideas / hints for solving this problem from you would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Without data we can only speculate as to what to problem might be. If it works outside of `rmarkdown`, i.e. in a regular R session, you could try to explicitly set `Sys.setlocale()` in the markdown file, with the values of `Sys.getlocale()` from the session where it works. Another possibility is looking at the *encoding* argument to `source`.

Comment: Make sure your R chunks, if named, are all uniquely named. You could try using just 1 external.R script and then add them and see where the issue is without being able to see all the code. Also maybe restarting your R session, or you can post more R session/YAML header

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions. I have found the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the "call function" do work. The reason why 1–18 became 1â€“18 is because the dash "–" came from non-standard keyboard or Copy-Paste, which can not be recognised in regular R script. However, theses special characters can be recognised in R Markdown.